# How do I bind an Entity Object to WPF TextBox?

Tags: entity-framework, xaml, textbox, binding

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here but I can't get basic binding to work with objects from my EDM.

Here's my xaml:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=receipt.STATUS}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="371,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

Here's my View code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _vw = new SimpleViewModel();
    DataContext = _vw;
}
```

Here's my ViewModel:

```
class SimpleViewModel
{
    private MyEntities _context;
    public RECEIPT receipt;
    ...
    public void GetReceipt(receiptKey)
    {
        IQueryable<RECEIPT> r = from it in _context.RECEIPTs
                                      where it.RECEIPTKEY == receiptKey
                                      select it;
        receipt = r.First();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're not calling GetReceipt... And even if do call it, receipt should be a property, not a field, and SimpleViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that the view can be notified when the value changes

Comment: That's it.  For some reason I thought the Entity Object fired the PropertyChanged event.  Thanks!